# Flexible Font Size for fixed width and height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fonts

I need to make each of my `<p>` have flexible font size with fixed width and height.

Current code

CSS

```
p{
    width:500px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#F0F0F0;
    margin:10px;
    padding:5px;
    font-size:24px;
}
```

HTML

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra quis dui a laoreet. Proin nibh dolor, faucibus sit amet aliquet ac, varius id eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra quis dui a laoreet. Proin nibh dolor, faucibus sit amet aliquet ac, varius id eros. consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra quis dui a laoreet. Proin nibh dolor, faucibus sit amet aliquet ac, varius id eros.</p>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra quis dui a laoreet. Proin nibh dolor, faucibus sit amet aliquet ac, varius id eros, faucibus sit amet aliquet ac, varius id eros.</p>
<br><br><br>

<!-- This one is perfect -->
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra quis dui a laoreet. Proin nibh dolor, faucibus sit amet aliquet ac, varius id eros.</p>
```

Check and try the code in jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/8GNAV/

And this the output I want to reach

http://jsfiddle.net/8GNAV/1/

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more for us? What do you mean 'flexible font size'? Are you asking how to create fixed sized 'boxes' with variable lengths of type but you always want the type to completely fill the box?

Comment: @DA. I want to make the font size fit the p's width and height, check this link http://jsfiddle.net/8GNAV/1/, I want to reach this output

Comment: So, yes, I think you want the type to 'expand to fit' the bounding box. There are plugins for this. Here's one: http://fittextjs.com/

Comment: @DA. **"Oh, and don't you dare let us catch you using FitText on paragraph text. This is for gigantic display text only!"** :D

Comment: I'll leave it up to you as to whether or not you want to abide by their design advice. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general idea is to get `overflow:hidden`, then keep shrinking the text until the `scrollHeight` is less than the `offsetHeight`. Like so:

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('p'),function(p) {
  p.style.overflow = "hidden";
  var f = 24;
  while(f > 6 && p.scrollHeight > p.offsetHeight) {
    f--;
    p.style.fontSize = f+"px";
  }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8GNAV/2/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I have question about performance, Is this solution will affect page performance (Using  while)?, lets say I will apply this function on maximum 30 p on the page, Sorry if the question is stupid, I'm newbie to javascript

Comment: It may cause a slight delay when the page is first loaded, but nothing noticeable.