# text within fixed block element to have scalable length

Tags: html, css

Here's my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HerrLoop/AsanM/)

And here's the markup (css in fiddle).

```
<div class="item">
    <a href="#">
        <span class="title">Short Title </span><br/>
        <span class="date">June 21st, 2013</span>
    </a>
</div>okay, this is good
<br/><br/>
<div class="item">
    <a href="#">
        <span class="title">A title which is medium </span><br/>
        <span class="date">June 21st, 2013</span>
    </a>
</div>still working...
<br/><br/>
<div class="item">
    <a href="#">
        <span class="title">A much longer title than normal to accommodate </span><br/>
        <span class="date">June 21st, 2013</span>
    </a>
</div>yikes, it's being pushed down
<br/><br/>
<div class="item-ideal">
    <a href="#">
        <span class="title">A much longer title than normal to accommodate </span><br/>
        <span class="date">June 21st, 2013</span>
    </a>
</div>how I want it to look in this case
```

Look through all 4 of the..  The 4th div has a unique class which hardcodes ideal dimension.

Are there any creative solutions to make this work?  **I want the block a tags to remain the same size.**

Answer (score 1):

use min-height instead of height

```
a{min-height:70px;}
```

Comment: A quick fix.  Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Unfortunately, I failed to mention in the question that I wanted all of the items to be the same size, so this won't work.

Comment: so increase height of the blocks

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `height` attribute from your `a` CSS rule.

```
a {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  /* height: 70px; */
  padding: 20px;
  background: black;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px black;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AsanM/1/

Comment: Thanks, but I want them all to be the same height.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to center vertically in the div.

Here's how you do this:

In css:

```
 #floater   {float:left; height:50%; margin-bottom:-55px;}
 #content   {clear:both; height:110px; position:relative;}
```

In html:

```
 <div id="floater">
 <div id="content">
    Content here
 </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `height` of your `a` to either `min-height` or `auto`.

Enclose the `span`s that are inside the `a` with another span.

Add `display:table;` to the new span.

Add `display:table-cell` and `vertical-align:center;` to the existing `a`.

Worked when I tried it on your Fiddle, wish I had more time, hope it helps. =)

Answer (score 0):

See that question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17220219/flexible-font-size-for-fixed-width-and-height), if you want to keep the size that you want and change the size of the text depending on his length.